# Python equivalent for C# query

Tags: c#, python, .net, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to replicate the C# method to python, I got stuck near the query

`var handler = from handler in _message`

```
private JObject ProcessMessage(JObject json)
{
    var type = GetProperty(json, TypeField).ToString();
    message = GetProperty(json, MsgField).ToString();
    var handlers = from handler in _message
                   where handler.Type == type && handler.Name == msg                                 
                   select handler;
    var selected = handlers.FirstOrDefault();
    return selected.Process(json);  
}
```

here is python code I have tried,

```
def process_message(self):
    type=get_property(self,translator.TypeField)
    message=get_property(self,translator.MsgField)


def get_property(self, TypeField):
    type_token = self.get(TypeField)
    return type_token
```

Comment: This is C# Linq, there might not be an exact replacement, you need to create logic to achieve it using for loop, if clause and store the details of first match, as that's what you need when you do `FirstOrDefault`. Also there'c a chance that `selected is null`, you need to make a check

Comment: Five language tags .... of which 2 conflict with each other - unless you _reallly_ need a py3 + 2.7 version of your c# code ....

Comment: Directly translating C# to Python makes no sense, the philosophies of the languages differ too much. Just give as an example input and tell us what you are trying to archive.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your python code.

First of all, I'm assuming you want to pass a JSON object as a parameter to process_message. I'm also assuming your code is inside a class. In that case, you want to write `process_message(self, json)`, not just `process_message(self)`.

Secondly, `get_property` is redundant. You can replace it with just `type = json.get(translator.TypeField)` for example.

As for the query, you can use list comprehension:

```
handlers = [h for h in _message if h.type == type and h.name == message]
```

In the end, we get something like this:

```
def process_message(self, json):
    type = json.get(translator.type_field)
    message = json.get(translator.msg_field)
    selected = [h for h in _message if h.type == type and h.name == message]

    if len(selected) > 0:
        return selected[0].process(json)
```

I replaced your naming with lowercase, since in python, it's convention to mark field names as such.